# how to convert a string to array of arrays in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that contain one column

```
     df.show(1)
     table
     [[,,hello,yes],[take,no,I,m],[hi,good,,]....]
     df.printSchema
     root
     |--table:string  (nullable:true)
```

My problem is how to convert that column to array of arrays: T.ArrayType(T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

Answer (score 4):

Use **`from_json`** function from **`Spark-2.4+`**

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,False)
#+---------------------------------------------+
#|table                                        |
#+---------------------------------------------+
#|[['','','hello','yes'],['take','no','i','m']]|
#+---------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- table: string (nullable = true)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#schema
sch=ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withColumn("dd",from_json(col("table"),sch)).select("dd").show(10,False)
#+------------------------------------+
#|dd                                  |
#+------------------------------------+
#|[[, , hello, yes], [take, no, i, m]]|
#+------------------------------------+

#schema after converting to array
df.withColumn("dd",from_json(col("table"),sch)).select("dd").printSchema()
#root
# |-- dd: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
# |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

**`spark>=2.4`**

Use combination of **`translate`** and **`regex_replace`**

```scala
  val df = Seq("[[,,hello,yes],[take,no,I,m],[hi,good,,]]").toDF("table")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +-----------------------------------------+
      * |table                                    |
      * +-----------------------------------------+
      * |[[,,hello,yes],[take,no,I,m],[hi,good,,]]|
      * +-----------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- table: string (nullable = true)
      */

    val  p = df.withColumn("arr", split(
      translate(
        regexp_replace($"table", """\]\s*,\s*\[""", "##"), "][", ""
      ), "##"
    ))

    val processed = p.withColumn("arr", expr("TRANSFORM(arr, x -> split(x, ','))"))

    processed.show(false)
    processed.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
      * |table                                    |arr                                                 |
      * +-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
      * |[[,,hello,yes],[take,no,I,m],[hi,good,,]]|[[, , hello, yes], [take, no, I, m], [hi, good, , ]]|
      * +-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- table: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
      */
```